# Loading partial with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a link_to button that loads with a partial with js.

Here is the link:

```
<%= link_to "See all...", questions_post_comment_path, class: "button", id: "new_link", :remote => true %>
```

The partial i'm loading looks like this:

```
<% @content.each do |content| %>
   <%= link_to "Link", my_path %>
<% end %>
```

and here is the js:

```
$('#new_link').html("<%= j (render :partial => 'questions') %>");
```

Everything loads fine but now instead of being linked to 'my_path' each link goes to questions_post_comment_path and each link in the partial is affected by the 'button' class. 
How do i load the partial on a click without affecting the partials contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#new_link').replaceWith("<%= j (render :partial => 'questions') %>");
```

Comment: You're welcome. With html function you're putting the partial into a#new_link tag.